# iTextSharp add image from route

Tags: itext

I'm trying to retrieve an image in iTextSharp. The image is retrieved by calling: local.myapp.com/File/FileDownload/102737. The images are in a database and the FileDownload actionresult method gets the image according to the id provided.

I'm trying to call above url from with a C# class (not controller) like this

```
iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"{imgName}"));
```

However I'm not able to make it work. I get wrong path something beginning with: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\

Comment: You're using `Server.MapPath()` incorrectly. Should be `Server.MapPath("~/images/imgage.jpg")`, where `~/images/imgage.jpg` is the path to the image. Not sure where you're getting `$"{imgName}"` from....that's not C#.

Comment: The image is generated dynamically from the database, by calling File/FileDownload/imageid. File is the controller and filedownload is the method inside it: public ActionResult FileDownload(string id)

Comment: So you want to retrieve your image via http download?

Comment: yes I guess it has to be retrieved through http

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments to the question, the image

> has to be retrieved through http.

Thus,  instead of using the `Image.GetInstance` overload with a `string` argument (which assumes the argument to be a file name in the local file system), use the overload with an `Uri` argument:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an instance of an Image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">an URL</param>
    /// <returns>an object of type Gif, Jpeg or Png</returns>
    public static Image GetInstance(Uri url)
```

Comment: I have changed the application so that a method can be called which return the image in a byte array. That has solved the problem.